# How can I programatically combine many images into one?

Tags: image, panoramas

I am looking for a way to write a script that will take around 400 png images and merge/combine them into one.

I have spent days playing and failing with image processing libraries for Python and C++.

If anyone could point me to a specific language or library that you know has this feature that would be awesome.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use an existing solution such as Canon's PhotoStitch or Photoshop (which has the best merger for making panoramas I've ever used). Just thought I'd suggest those before you go reinventing the wheel.

Comment: **UPDATE:** I have changed "stitch" to "combine" in this question, as the accepted answer doesn't provide stitching, but simply combining. (“Stitching” involves combining overlapping images so that the overlapping portions align. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_stitching)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) libraries and tools both support this.

Example [link](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php):

```
 montage -background #336699 -geometry +4+4 rose.jpg red-ball.png montage.jpg
```

Or

```
convert image1.jpg image2.jpg +append output.jpg
```

You can also blend over lapping photo's togeather as listed in [this](http://imagemagick.org/Usage/photos/#overlap) article.

Comment: I used ImageMagick and it worked perfect, I got done exactly what I had wanted thanks!.